# how to handle null values in this linq-sql query

Tags: linq-to-sql

```
var query = (from student in dataset.Students
             where student.subjectId == SubjectId || student.subjectId ==dataset.Subjects.FindBySubjecttId(SubjectId).PrimarySubjectId                 
                                 select student)
```

The above Linq to SQL query fails if  PrimarySubjectId is null.

PrimarySubjectId can have null values in the database. If there is no record for the subjectId I want the PrimarySubjectId which can be null. How do i handle the null values for 
PrimarySubjectId ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var query = (from student in dataset.Students

                 where student.subjectId == SubjectId || 

 student.subjectId==dataset.Subjects.FindBySubjecttId(SubjectId).PrimarySubjectId                 
select student)
```

Since your PrimarySubjectId allows null so as per your linq statement, the property student.subjectid must be allowed to accept null values by making it Nullable subjectId or int? subjectid.